# ReacriveX(ReactiveExtension/System.Reactive)のソース(C#)をVisualStudio上で読めるようにできないでしょうか？

Tags: c#, visual-studio

## 質問の導入部

自身のプロジェクトにReacriveX(NuGetパッケージ名:System.Reactive)をインストールして利用しているのですが、このライブラリが持つメソッドの中身を掘り下げるように確認したくなることがあります。

そこで、公開されているソースを探しそれをGitHub上(https://github.com/dotnet/reactive)に見つけましたが、掘り下げていくのが大変面倒です。

## 質問

そこで、利便性を上げるべくMSViusualStudio上で確認できるようにしたいです。
たとえば、自身のプロジェクトで利用しているライブラリメソッドから、F12キーでその定義へ飛んで中身を確認できるようなことがしたいです。

なにか良い方法はないでしょうか。

## 注意事項

NuGetパッケージをインストールするだけでも、メソッドの定義（シグニチャ）までは見れるのですが、その中身については見ることができません。
あくまで中身も見れることが重要です。

Answer (score 0):

次善策ですが、見つかったものを投稿しておこうと思います。
よりよい方法がありましたら、投稿していただけると嬉しいです。

- GitHubからReactiveXをクローンする
- 自身でビルドする
- ビルドしてできたDLLへの参照と、ReactiveXのプロジェクトへの参照を、自身のプロジェクトへ追加する

ソースサーバーなるもにソースが公開されていれば、それを利用すればよいといった案も得られましたが、それについて調べきれなかったため、ソースサーバーの利用は見送ります（できれば使いたいですが）。